# How do I change a field type using FieldTypeDeclaration ( Roslyn )

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using the visual studio project type - Stand-Alone Code Analysis Tool. I am using the following code but the ToString() is showing an unexpected result.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var classDoc = @"public class SomeClass{
            private SomeOtherClass someOtherClass;
        }";

    SyntaxTree classTree=SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(classDoc);
    var classDecl = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)classTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes()
        .First(d => d is ClassDeclarationSyntax);

    var field = classDecl.Members.OfType<FieldDeclarationSyntax>().First();
    var fieldType = field.Declaration.Type;
    var newFieldType = SyntaxFactory.ParseName("System.Windows.Forms.UserControl");
    var newField=field.ReplaceNode(fieldType, newFieldType);
    var newFieldStr = newField.ToString();
}
```

The value of `newFieldStr` is

```
private System.Windows.Forms.UserControlsomeOtherClass;
```

Please advise how I can get the expected result.

Comment: I think you just need to either preserve the trivia from the old node or run the formatter.

Comment: Many thanks SLaks. I did not think that I would have to deal with trivia, I did think that changes to a syntax tree for a document in workspace would create spaces for me.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, you can just add the trivia from the original syntax node:

```
var newFieldType = SyntaxFactory.ParseName("System.Windows.Forms.UserControl")
                                .WithTriviaFrom(fieldType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this "one-liner" for doing all the work:

```
var newField = field.WithDeclaration(
                    field.Declaration.WithType(
                            SyntaxFactory.ParseName("System.Windows.Forms.UserControl")
                                         .WithTriviaFrom(field.Declaration.Type)));
```